# jQuery sliding panel- multiple links calling different sections of the panel

Tags: jquery, slider, panel

I'm trying to design and implement what seems like a simple solution. I have a drop-down panel tab at the top of the page with 3 links in it- about, resume and contact, and an arrow to drop it. I'd like the panel to drop down and show the specific content for the link I clicked on, and swap the arrow to point up to close it.

For example, click on about, panel drops down and show about info. Click resume, same panel drops to show resume info. While the panel is dropped, be able to toggle between the 3 sections.

In essence, combine the sliding panel with the 'coda' style horizontal slide.

Is this possible? Visit http://www.dannylewandowski.com/panel.png for a rough layout for reference.

Thanks so much for any help!!!!
Best
Danny

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI has kinda what you are looking for I think.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#collapsible